# Redux + Reselect: Preventing selector recalculation when GPS data updates

Tags: reactjs, data-structures, redux, reselect

Recently, I've been working on a very large application using React+Redux with Reselect to memoize data and prevent unnecessary re-renders, and I've hit a specific problem that I can't seem to get past.

In Redux state, I am storing a very large amount of data as an object indexed by id. These objects all have a property on them (let's call it gps) that updates with realtime gps coordinates.

This data is being used in two ways. The first is on a map, where the GPS data is relevant. The second is in the UI, where the GPS data is not relevant. Any time the GPS data is updated on any of the objects, that object is streamed in and replaced in the Redux store, which updates the reference of that object in my selector.

Example Redux Store:

```
data: {
   dogs: {
      1: {id: 1, name: "name1", gps: [123, 234]},
      2: {id: 2, name: "name2", gps: [123, 234]},
      3: {id: 3, name: "name3", gps: [123, 234]},
      4: {id: 4, name: "name4", gps: [123, 234]}
   }
}
```

The data in, for example, state.dogs[1].gps might updated 3 to 5 times per second. This can occur in any of the objects in state.data.dogs.

Selectors are written as follows:

```
const dogDataSelector = state => state.data.dogs;

const animalsSelector = createSelector(
    dogDataSelector,
    (dogs) => {
        return Object.keys(dogs).map(id => {
            return dogs[id];
        })
    }
)
```

Now, this code works correctly when I want all the dogs, as they update, GPS included.

What I can't seem to figure out would be how to write a selector specifically for the UI that excludes the GPS updates. 99 times out of 100, when a dog updates, it is the GPS updating. The UI doesn't care about the GPS at all, but due to that, the selector sends new data forward which causes the UI to rerender.

I know it is possible to write a new stream that only pushes changes from the DB if the id or name of a dog changes, but this is a solution I am hoping to stay away from, as it will cause a lot of the same data to be stored multiple times in the store.

I have tried the following:

- creating a selector that returns a pared-down version of the dogs, with only the id and the name, stored in an object by keys. This selector is used as an input-selector later, but still causes unnecessary selector returns.
- creating a selector that only returns an array of dog ids, and passing this to the UI. A deep equality check is used to prevent re-renders, and the array of ids is used to pluck specific dog objects from state. This is not an ideal solution and seems bad.

If anyone needs any more information or clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

Update: One of the main reasons this is an issue is that any GPS update to any dog will cause the dogDataSelector to return a new reference. This will, in turn, cause animalsSelector fire an update and return a new value.

Comment: I think the solution is to customise the equality check, using `createSelectorCreator` - see https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#customize-equalitycheck-for-defaultmemoize

Comment: @DavidKemp this is one solution I have toyed with, and how it is currently implemented. It works, but it could be better, as the amount of data coming through can be 5000+ items, and at this point, the extra rendering seems less expensive than an equality check. Thank you for your help, though! If I can't implement a better solution, this is what I will be going with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach for immutable data updates requires that if a nested field is updated, all of its ancestors in the tree should be copied and updated as well.  In your example, an update to `dog[3].gps` would require new references for the `gps` array, `dog[3]`, `dogs`, and `data`.  Because of that, with this data structure, any updates to a `gps` field *must* result in new references all the way up the chain, and so the UI would see the new references and assume it needs to re-render.

A couple possible suggestions:

- Write a selector that looks up a dog entry by its ID, strip out the `gps` field, and then do some kind of shallow equality check against the prior value to see if any if the non-`gps` fields have actually changed, so that a new "dog entry minus `gps`" object is only returned when one of those fields is different.
- Store the GPS values in a separate lookup table keyed by ID, rather than nested inside the dog entries themselves, so that updates to a GPS array don't result in new dog entry references.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid equality checks (at least deep equality checks) as the `dog` object can contain 5000+ items. 

Both of those solutions are incredibly helpful, however!

When writing a selector, I'd need one that returns the entirety of the `state.data.dogs` object each time. My stream will send an update across any time any of the 5000+ dogs have an update to anything, including GPS. Would your proposed solution still work in this case? Is it possible to write a selector that can rip GPS off of all of the `dogs` and then use that as in input selector later without a reference update?

Comment: Your second solution also seems really good, and may be better in the long run. I could update my backend to include two streams; one, a GPS stream, and another a name/id/whatever stream, and have both of these stored in different places. On my map, grab both GPS and information, and in the UI just grab information.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: THIS WON'T WORK FOR REASONS DETAILED IN THE COMMENTS**

If you don't need the gps data, then surely you can just strip it off, and `reselect` will ignore it

Something like:

```
const dogDataSelector = state => state.data.dogs;

const animalsSelector = createSelector(
    dogDataSelector,
    (dogs) => {
        return Object.keys(dogs).map(id => {
            return dogs[id];
        })
    },
    (dogsArray) => dogsArray.map(({id, name}) => ({id, name}))
)
```

Comment: The problem here is that proper immutable updates to the `gps` arrays will result in new references up the chain, causing this selector to always recalculate every time and never memoize properly.

Comment: @markerikson is correct, that's the issue I've been struggling with. The dogDataSelector input-selector will show an update every time gps updates on a dog and cause a new return from animalsSelector

Comment: @naturalrouge can you add that information to the question?

Comment: @DavidKemp definitely, will do!